# Is it possible to include modules I used when compiling a .jar?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have very minimal knowledge of Java, coming from a mainly Python background, and I was wondering if it is possible to include the modules that I used with a .jar?

For example, my program uses Selenium Webdriver and Selenium Chromedriver, is it possible for me to make it so that my user doesn't need to have these installed?

Thank you and sorry if this has been asked before!

Comment: Are you using any tools like maven to build project

Comment: what do you mean by `my user`? which position your users have? API users or Program users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using maven then you can use   **maven-shade-plugin** and you can configure what you like to include and exclude from library  in your project build jar

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>junit:junit</artifact>
              <includes>
                <include>junit/framework/**</include>
                <include>org/junit/**</include>
              </includes>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>org/junit/experimental/**</exclude>
                <exclude>org/junit/runners/**</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

For more information see:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

You can also use **maven-assembly-plugin**

*The Assembly Plugin for Maven is primarily intended to allow users to aggregate the project output along with its dependencies, **modules**, site documentation, and other files into a single distributable archive* [more](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

I looked your pom file. So i am **posting** a **working sample pom** file that i made based on one you provided in **pastebin**.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.selenium.pro</groupId>
    <artifactId>packjar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>packing library with jar</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <filters>
                                        <filter>
                                            <artifact>junit:junit</artifact>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>junit/framework/**</include>
                                                <include>org/junit/**</include>
                                            </includes>
                                            <excludes>
                                                <exclude>org/junit/experimental/**</exclude>
                                                <exclude>org/junit/runners/**</exclude>
                                            </excludes>
                                        </filter>
                                        <filter>
                                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                            <excludes>
                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                            </excludes>
                                        </filter>
                                    </filters>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Normally for your development you don't need to pack library but you can verify it. When you have to build your application to client , you could run

```
mvn clean package -Pprod   //profile prod
```

and here is portion of build log

```
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade (default) @ packjar ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.2/asm-5.0.2.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.2/asm-5.0.2.jar (52 KB at 9.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Including org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.41.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:2.41.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:2.41.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.json:json:jar:20080701 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.guava:guava:jar:15.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.41.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.13 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.13 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01 in the shaded jar.
```

Note: If you are using signed library jars then this solution might not work for you.

Comment: I was already using maven, if I have a module under my dependencies, will it build with it included? For example, here is my pom.xml so far. http://pastebin.com/nykuA9HB Thanks!

Comment: I don't find you are using any plugin and configuration to accomodate library classess in your build jar.

Comment: You should accept answer if it make sense to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can include resources in your jar
See packaging using [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812209/maven-making-jars-with-dependencies-example-from-book-doesnt-work) or [Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821803/creating-a-bundle-jar-with-ant)

This will work for the **Selenium** dependency,but the **ChromeDriver** is an executable, so you will have to extract it before using it, see example here: [Run *.exe file from inside JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531766/run-exe-file-from-inside-jar)